# Cannot edit file on windows server through RDP as domain admin

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server

I'm new to windows administration. I've set up an Active Directory and created a user who is member of Domain Admins.

I've created another windows server, and logged into it in RDP with the Domain Admins user, but it seems i'm unable to modify files. Whenever I do it i'm prompted with "you do not have permission to open this file. etc...".

I looked at folder & file permission, and it seems only local administrator has right over it (and is owner).

Am I missing something or is this juste a misunderstanding from me of Domain Admins concept? I thought they had rights over anything by default in the domain.

Edit : Seems that using the the build-in account for administering the computer/domain (aka the local admin of the ActiveDirectory) works. But when I add a user to the same group as AD local admin, it doesn't. Can't figure out why.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several misunderstandings, even.

1. Being a member of the local "Administrator**s**" group is not the same as literally being the local "Administrator" account. Yes, usually it's the group membership that grants the privileges. But they are still distinct entities, and if a file's ACL *specifically* grants access to the "Admin" account, then only that account gets access – members of the "Admins" group do not automatically get access. The ACL needs to include the group explicitly.
2. Local admin rights do not let you bypass the ACL by default. They only let you take over files and *make* them accessible to yourself, but they still don't let you simply access stuff without being granted access.

   (Well, that's a slight lie; a process with local admin rights *can* activate SeBackupPrivilege and become able to read files that it normally wouldn't have access to. But that's deliberately not automatic and most programs just don't do that.)
3. If the computer has UAC enabled, membership in local Administrators is special and filtered out by UAC unless you run the program "elevated".
4. Finally, Domain Admins are not *inherently* local admins. The purpose of this group is to have admin rights over the Active Directory domain database – not over the machines themselves. (Except for the DCs.)

   The only thing that makes Domain Admins become local admins is being in the local "Administrators" group, as usual. Typically the entire Domain Admins group is a member.

   However, since Domain Admins are *highly* privileged (as in, they can destroy or compromise the entire domain), it is highly discouraged to use a Domain Admin account for regular server or workstation management, and to enforce this it's typical to use a GPO to revoke their local admin rights.

   Use `whoami /groups` to check whether you as a Domain Admin are in fact a member of Administrators or not.
5. The "local" Administrators group you see in AD is only for the domain controllers themselves, as those have no separate local accounts. It doesn't affect other member computers.

Answer (score 0):

You have run into the permissions difference between the Active directory
Administrators group and the Domain Administrators group.

The terminology here requires some explanation.

**Active directory Administrators** have full permission on all
domain controllers in the domain, but are not automatically granted
administrative access to all computers within the domain.

**Local Administrator** of a computer is really situated outside of
the domain and has the full power to do anything desired on the
local machine, said machine is PART of the domain.

**Domain Administrators** are also automatically members of the local
administrators group of each members machine in the domain.
They are also automatically members of the
Active directory Administrators group.

You may think of it as that Domain Administrators have more
permissions than Active directory Administrators.

The account you are using is evidently an Active directory Administrator.
You need to create a Domain Administrator account if you want
total control of all the computers on the local level.

It's not recommended to add by force your Active directory
Administrator account to the Local Administrators group,
as that will implicitly operate on all such accounts, and
not only on the specified one.